# Nodejs Request Parallel request with Bluebird response

Tags: node.js, request, bluebird, cheerio, request-promise

I have two url's that I have been requesting and using Bluebird promise library want to process the url's html with cheerio. I can't seem to get the result html. What should I be using inside spread ?

```
    let url1 = request('http://example1.com')
    let url2 = request('http://example2.com')

    Promise.all([url1, url2])
    .spread(function (url1RqRes, url2RqRes) {

        // How do I get access to the response html here ???

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'); // Basically jQuery for node.js
var rp = require('request-promise');

let url1 = rp('http://example1.com')
let url2 = rp('http://example2.com')

Promise.all([url1, url2])
.then(function (results) {
    console.log('results', results)
    let pages = results.map((resp) => cheerio.load(resp))
    // you will get the result in the same order of promise passed as array
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

for reference [request-promise with cheerio](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

Comment: thanks @zabusa but how do I get access to the document html ? that i loaded through sending a request. my main goal is to load the html into cheerio

Comment: @Deepankar console the results youcan see the response right?

Comment: its just whole lot of Request object. I can't get access to the document body

Comment: @Deepankar which are the libraries are you using?`request-promise`

Comment: m importing Promise from Bluebird, request from request

Comment: @Deepankar you need to import request-promise also `npm install request-promise --save`

Comment: oh I got it. I was just using Request and not Request-Promise. it works now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161373/discussion-between-deepankar-and-zabusa).